# froala editor rotate image when height is more than width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, froala

I use froala editor, and config for image upload plugin. The problem is that when I upload an image with height more than width, editor automatically rotate image.

you can test this problem in this demo page [**froala editor demo**](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/image-styles).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a newly [integration with Aviary](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/aviary) which you could use now for advanced image editing. It allays rich editing features such as crop, rotate and even filters.

[image]